# How are views from a mobile embedded player reported in YouTube Analytics?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm working on an iOS app that embeds the youtube player in a `UIWebView` with the IFrame API.
I've watched a few of my own videos in this player and have waited a day or two for view data to appear in the YouTube Analyics "Views reports". However no data has appeared yet.

Q1: Should I see views recorded? Has anyone else had analytics data collection issues?

Q2: If the data should appear, how is it reported? Will the "Playback location" and "Traffic source" be "Embedded players" or "Mobile devices"?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Yes =) Do you still not see them?

Q2: In Playback location there are "Mobile devices" (https://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1714546) You also have the new "Devices" report where you can see views from mobile devices broken down by Operating system. The views should of course also be included in the total views seen on the "Views" report.

Answer (score 0):

A1: Yes, eventually the views were reported although the counts don't match what I expected (perhaps some have been filtered as duplicates).

A2: They were reported as "Embedded player".  They weren't recorded as mobile in the "Devices" report either - came through under "Computer".